# Saving checkbox/radiobutton bool to global var

Tags: c#, wpf, global-variables, boolean

(using WPF application)
I get an error when i want to save a bool to a global variable like this:

```
Window msgOne = new Window();
 if (Properties.Settings.Default.sound01 == true)
  {
    msgOne.radioboxSound.IsChecked = true;
  }
 else
  {
    msgOne.radioboxSound.IsChecked = false;
  }
msgOne.ShowDialog();
//waiting for close
Properties.Settings.Default.sound01 = msgOne.radioboxSound.IsChecked;
```

where the `radioboxSound` is the checkbox, and the `Properties.Settings.Default.sound01` is the global parameter that you can make in the settings tab in VB c#

The error that i am getting for the last link of above snipit):
Cannot implicitly convert type "bool?" to "bool". An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast?)

But i don't have used any bool?, only bolls that have been set.

Anyone know how to deal with this one?

thanx

Comment: You do use a Nullable<bool> (aka bool?) because IsChecked is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The radio button's IsChecked property is a 'bool?'.  Change your code to

```
Properties.Settings.Default.sound01 = msgOne.radioboxSound.IsChecked??false;
```

A bit more explanation.

Since RadioButton.IsChecked is a Nullable, then regardless of whether the IsThreeState property is set to true or false you will need to handle the fact that IsChecked is nullable.

You could use

```
Properties.Settings.Default.sound01 = msgOne.radioboxSound.IsChecked == true;
```

or use the null coalescing operator as above.

Comment: This indeed fixes it, but could you explain a bit for my understanding?  the ??false -> Meaning, if it fails to get it somehow, it will set false?  or what does it do ?

Comment: Tha's right. It's the null coalescing operator and effectively shorthand for: msgOne.radioboxSound.IsChecked.HasValue ? msgOne.radioboxSound.IsChecked.Value : false;  Which is itself shorthand for if(..) ... else ...